# How do I connectStyle and connect in React Native?

Tags: react-native, redux, native-base

I'd like to export my component with native-base's `connectStyle` and Redux's `connect` but no luck so far. How do I correctly apply both to my component?

Example:

```
export default connectStyle('myTheme.myComponent', styles)(myComponent) connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(myComponent)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(connectStyle('myTheme.myComponent', styles)(myComponent))
```

This will `connect` the component returned from `connectStyle`. `connectStyle` returns  a component with props mapped to style, which then you can use as the component to connect dispatch and state to props.